Sign up modal re-renders and closes on API call made on submit- next js
I have a modal component that renders sign in and sign up forms conditionally and when I click the submit button on any of its forms the modal closes even if the call is unsuccessful.
I deployed my code in this repo.
This is my modal:
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Modal from "@mui/material/Modal";
import SigninForm from "./signin-form";
import SignupForm from "./signup-form";
import { PiUserCircle } from "react-icons/pi";


export interface InputProps {
  inputs: {
    name: string;
    city: string;
    email: string;
    phone: string;
    password: string;
  };
  handleChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  handleClose: () => void;
}

export default function LoginModal() {
  const [isSignin, setIsSignin] = useState(false);

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => {
    console.log("handle close called");
    setOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Modal state:", open);
  }, [open]);

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    name: "",
    city: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputs({
      ...inputs,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const props = {
    inputs,
    handleChange,
    handleClose,
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <PiUserCircle size={30} className="text-primary" onClick={handleOpen} />
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          {isSignin ? (
            <>
              <SigninForm props={props} />
              <p className="text-center">
                do not have an account?{" "}
                <button
                  className="bg-secondary outline-0 border-0 underline"
                  onClick={() => setIsSignin(false)}
                >
                  make one!
                </button>
              </p>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <SignupForm props={props} />
              <p className="text-center">
                have an account?{" "}
                <button
                  className="bg-secondary outline-0 border-0 underline"
                  onClick={() => setIsSignin(true)}
                >
                  sign in!
                </button>
              </p>
            </>
          )}
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

I did this part so I know if the modal closes by itself or by my hook and nothing logged but false, false:
const handleClose = () => {
    console.log("handle close called");
    setOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Modal state:", open);
  }, [open]);

and this is the sign up form component, the wrapper is just a div with styles; preventing default didn't work both in form onsubmit and button onclick:
import LoginWrapper from "./login-wrapper";
import { InputProps } from "./login-modal";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useAuth from "../../../hooks/useAuth";
import { AuthorizationContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import spinner from "../../icons/spinner.png";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function SignupForm({ props }: { props: InputProps }) {
  const { inputs, handleChange, handleClose } = props;
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const { signup } = useAuth();
  const { data, error, loading, setAuthState } =
    useContext(AuthorizationContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      inputs.name &&
      inputs.city &&
      inputs.email &&
      inputs.password &&
      inputs.phone
    ) {
      setDisabled(false);
    } else {
      setDisabled(true);
    }
  }, [inputs]);

  return (
    <LoginWrapper>
      {loading ? (
        <Image src={spinner} alt="loading" />
      ) : (
        <>
          <div>welcome</div>
          <div>register</div>
          <form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
            }}
            className="flex flex-col gap-4 *:w-60 *:rounded-md *:p-2"
          >
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              id="name"
              placeholder="name"
              value={inputs.name}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="city"
              id="city"
              placeholder="city"
              value={inputs.city}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="phone"
              id="phone"
              placeholder="phone"
              value={inputs.phone}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            />
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              id="email"
              placeholder="email"
              value={inputs.email}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              id="password"
              placeholder="password"
              value={inputs.password}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            />
            <button
              disabled={disabled}
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                signup(inputs, handleClose);
              }}
              className="bg-primary text-white disabled:bg-secondary disabled:border disabled:border-primary disabled:text-primary"
            >
              Sign Up
            </button>
          </form>
          <h1>{error ? error : ""}</h1>
        </>
      )}
    </LoginWrapper>
  );
}

This is the custom hook for making API call:
import axios from "axios";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthorizationContext } from "../app/context/AuthContext";
import { deleteCookie } from "cookies-next";

export default const useAuth = () => {
  const { setAuthState } = useContext(AuthorizationContext);

  const signin = async (
    { email, password }: { email: string; password: string },
    handleClose: () => void
  ) => {
    setAuthState({
      data: null,
      error: null,
      loading: true,
    });

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`/api/auth/signin`, {
        email,
        password,
      });

      setAuthState({
        data: response.data,
        error: null,
        loading: false,
      });
      if (response.status === 200 && response.data) {
        handleClose();
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
      setAuthState({
        data: null,
        error: error.response.data.errorMessage,
        loading: false,
      });
    }
  };

  const signup = async (
    {
      email,
      password,
      name,
      phone,
      city,
    }: {
      email: string;
      password: string;
      name: string;
      phone: string;
      city: string;
    },
    handleClose: () => void
  ) => {
    setAuthState({
      data: null,
      error: null,
      loading: true,
    });

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`/api/auth/signup`, {
        email,
        password,
        name,
        phone,
        city,
      });

      setAuthState({
        data: response.data,
        error: null,
        loading: false,
      });
      if (response.status === 200 && response.data) {
        handleClose();
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
      setAuthState({
        data: null,
        error: error.response.data.errorMessage,
        loading: false,
      });
    }
  };

  const signout = () => {
    deleteCookie("jwt");
    setAuthState({
      data: null,
      error: null,
      loading: false,
    });
  };
  return {
    signin,
    signup,
    signout,
  };
};


I want it to get closed only when the sign up is successful.

Let me ask what type of data you have? If it is an array, it is best to check like this.

if (response.status === 200 && response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
handleClose();
}


no matter what type handleClose won't be called when the modal closes on itself
